# Swift - Instance "not constructible with '...." from "static" method

Tags: ios, swift

When I try to instantiate a class through "static" method (required from protocol), the compiler don't recognize the initializer, although I pass correct parameters.

[image]

[image]

Comment: how is `User` defined? or more specifically, what does it's initializer look like?

Comment: is a empty class, has no propertie or initializer @drewag. even if I remove author and Interaction superclass it will fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are defining a template called "Comment" in your method declaration that is obscuring the real `Comment` class. You need to give that template argument a different name.

And I believe your JSONSerializable protocol is not defined the way you want it. You can use `Self` in a protocol to refer to the class implementing the protocol so there is no need for a template. Your protocol could look like this:

```
protocol JSONSerializable {
    class func instanceFrom(json: [String:AnyObject]) -> Self;
}
```

Then you would implement this method in your Comment class:

```
class Comment: JSONSerializable {
    ...

    class func instanceFrom(json: [String:AnyObject]) -> Comment {
        return Comment(message: "lorem lorem", author: User())
    }
}
```

However, it is preferred in Swift to use initializers instead of class methods:

```
protocol JSONSerializable {
    init(json: [String:AnyObject])
}

class Comment: JSONSerializable {
    ...

    init(json: [String : AnyObject]) {
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect! I believe that I'm still thinking Java Generics and tried to apply the same concept here. I don't knew Self. thanks!

Comment: I don't use initializers because instanceFrom is a specific builder method. I could extract it to extension class, I don't know.. This type can be created from other source (sqlite, by hands or Realm lib) too